# How can I get the Lisp garbage collector to remove foreign c++ allocated memory in my class slots?

Tags: garbage-collection, common-lisp, finalizer

My class looks like this:

```
(defclass matrix ()
  ((rows :initarg :rows :initform 2)
   (cols :initarg :cols :initform 2)
   (matrix :accessor matrix)))
```

I have a specialisation of the initialize-instance method which creates the object for the matrix slot by calling into a c++ library.  I have a matrix-destroy function which will free the memory allocated in c++.

What I want is to be able to get the garbage collector to call matrix-destroy on the matrix slot.  Is there an idiomatic way to do this in common lisp?

Comment: You can set a finalizer for the object. How that happens depends on the Lisp implementation, but you can use the [Trivial Garbage](https://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-garbage/) to do it portably.

Comment: @jkiiski do you have a link to sample code using trivial garbage? I just checked its documentation and it seems sparse. Actually, I just checked the index of Common Lisp Recipies and it has a discussion of finalizers so I am off to read it, but a link would be nice.

Comment: SBCL manual has a short [example](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Garbage-Collection) for how to use it. Basically just call `FINALIZE` on the object after creating it (make sure to not refer to the object itself in the finalizer function. You can refer to the foreign handle). You can also see [cl-sdl2](https://github.com/lispgames/cl-sdl2), which uses finalizers to free surfaces/textures/etc. (see [`SDL-COLLECT`](https://github.com/lispgames/cl-sdl2/blob/master/src/sdl2.lisp) for where the finalizer is set).

Comment: @jkiiski thanks for the tips and help. I've figured it out now.

Comment: How about making it an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run a function after the garbage collector has collecte an object, you need to set a finalizer for that object. The Common Lisp standard does not include finalizers, but implementations do provide them. There is a compatibility library called [Trivial Garbage](https://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-garbage/) that you can use to set them portably.

Setting a finalizer happens by simply calling `FINALIZE` on the object you want to attach the finalizer to. The finalizer function must not contain any references to the object itself, as that would prevent it from ever being collected. You should also keep in mind that the finalizer may be executed at any time in any thread, so it should be re-entrant and not depend on any specific dynamic environment.

SBCL manual has a short example for finalizers in [7.4 Garbage Collection](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Garbage-Collection). You can also see some existing project that uses them, such as [cl-sdl2](https://github.com/lispgames/cl-sdl2), which uses them to free SDL surfaces, textures and such. See [`SDL-COLLECT`](https://github.com/lispgames/cl-sdl2/blob/master/src/sdl2.lisp#L22) for where the finalizer is set, and [`CREATE-RGB-SURFACE`](https://github.com/lispgames/cl-sdl2/blob/master/src/surface.lisp#L23) for an example of where `SDL-COLLECT` is called from.